# Can't run my flutter app on an ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

i have been developing my app on android for a while and today started attempting to test on an ios simulator, after finishing all the required installations, cocoapods and such, my test app works but my real app is not, getting several errors on the ios simulator but not on android emulator, can anyone help?

These are the final lines

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] <PBXGroup UUID=97C146E51CF9000F007C117D> attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. CF3B75C9A7D2FA2A4C99F110 for attribute: children. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 8.0 on target Runner because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.

Edit: Set of errors I'm getting from xcode

`app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')`

`:-1: Capabilities for Runner may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the build settings editor. (in target 'Runner')`

`There are no accounts registered with Xcode. (Add your developer account to Xcode)`

Comment: Try open your project and build on XCode.

Comment: Do I open the ios folder only? because when i try to open the main app folder, i get an error that xcode can't open it

Comment: On your flutter project you have a `ios` folder, that contain the XCode project.

Comment: got several warnings and one error when running, the error is `:-1: app/ios/app/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')`

Comment: Type `open Runner.xcworkspace` (I think that is the name or similar) on your terminal.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but does xcode has a terminal? or you mean the AS or mac terminals?

Comment: You can open your project on XCode from terminal :). You is making it on a macOS, correct?

Comment: yes, but this is the first time I use xcode, as I said I was only going for the android side of things for all my development phase, now I migrated to a new pc to go for the mac side and that happened, i will check how i can open it on Xcode from terminal now

Comment: getting several errors and warnings `app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')` && `:-1: Capabilities for Runner may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the build settings editor. (in target 'Runner')` && `There are no accounts registered with Xcode. (Add your developer account to Xcode)` do i need an account to run it on a simulator?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but this message tells to you have :), so if you haven't it, create.

Comment: while i will start doing that, i don't think that is the issue since a test app works fine (the default app I mean)

Comment: Sometimes you must build your project on XCode because some dependencies or settings not are made by Flutter alone.

Comment: Can the reason for this be that i downloaded this from github rather than start it on the mac device?

Answer (score 0):

See your all dependencies proper install or not see that ios supported or not

Comment: Please provide more clarity, how do I do this? Where do I check this?